# How to Pick target Texture When Rendering With F12

Tags: rendering

I want to render textures but when I press F12 to render, it always renders to the first image present in the image editor list. I’d like to pick the target texture I want to render to.

UPDATE: I'm talking about `rendering` not `baking`.

I’m going through all the different texture maps one by one (color, metalness, roughness ect.) and I need to be able to choose for each time I want to render with F12 to which texture it should render.

How can I pick the target texture when pressing F12 to render?

Comment: If my post helped answer your question, please consider marking it as the thread solution.

Comment: Additionally I would say that F12 is Rendering from the selected camera and has nothing to do with "Bake". So @RandomPanda 's answer is correct tho, but the question is quite ambiguous and misleading. 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141485/baking-textures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an extra image / UV node. Blender treats selected image nodes as the image to be baked onto.

**Note:** You will have to setup these nodes for every material you want included in the baking process.

[image]

Comment: For how this question was received. I guess this is the only correct answer here. Baking is the only way you can choose the texture you want to bake to. It seems, that it is not possible when rendering with f12, at all. So the only way to do it is with baking.